# why could a print statement in python file causing [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, python-3.x, py4j

Is it possible that one could see a `[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` error message caused from a `print()` statement?

I was facing this error at random (sometimes in a row, sometimes it did not occur at all) while running unittests. As soon as I removed the print statements that the file was complaining about things ran fine.

What would cause that error for a print message?

Comment: Are you passing a `file=...` argument to `print()`?  Or does your code muck around with `sys.stdout`?

Comment: @JohnGordon this file https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/blob/master/pydeequ/scala_utils.py is what I'm working with. Line 24 is what seems to cause issues

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when `stdout` is busy/locked by the system. Sounds like your program requires quite a few resources to run? In your case, I'd just wrap it in a `try/except` or add some delay in your code, maybe optimize the code or use another method to get reliable output.